# Idiom for someone getting popular by hanging with an already popular person

Tags: idioms

I want to remember what's the idiom for this situation:
someone getting popular by hanging with an already popular person.
I barely remember it was something like
"hanging from someone else's popularity".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "[Riding (someone's) coattails](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ride+coattails)" may be what you're thinking of, but it's not quite about popularity so much as success, so not sure if that's really what you want.

Comment: Actually it isn't, but i recall reading once that one too. Thanks! I'll be using that one for now. But i would like to let this question open for a week or two before closing it. Hopefully someone will know what idiom i'm talking about.

Comment: **[Basking in reflected glory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basking_in_reflected_glory)** may be just what you're looking for. Failing that, you might want to **[Hitch your wagon to a star](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hitch+wagon+to+a+star)**.

Comment: I believe this might be it. Thank you so much. But i still would like to let this question open for a week or two before closing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible answers. Some that come closest may be:

- **[Ride somebody's coattails](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ride+coattails)**
- **[Basking in reflected glory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basking_in_reflected_glory)**
- **[Hitch your wagon to a star](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hitch+wagon+to+a+star)**